# Ubuntu 17.04 – login loop when using GNOME Default, but oddly works when I select GNOME Classic or Unity

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

Obviously, `.Xauthority` and `.ICEauthority` have the correct permissions, as not only did I check the permissions, but I can login by selecting certain desktop environments. The user, however, doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: same problem here